# Physically moving a Linux system HDD to another machine (Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, boot, uefi

I have a functioning <s>Unix</s> Linux system (Ubuntu server) on machine A and a functioning Windows (10) on machine B.

I would like to only keep B by moving A's HDD into it and create a bootloader to choose between the two systems on startup.

I naively installed the A's HDD on B, it is detected by the BIOS, but not as a bootable device. I installed EasyUEFI on windows, but <s>Unix</s> Linux HDD is not recognized as something I can boot on. My expertise in this domain is somewhere near 0.

I also tried [bcdedit here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries): I can easily add a boot entry, but I don't know how to point to the Ubuntu EFI file, on the right drive.

How to create a bootloader that shows both systems?

Please not that I'm not asking about migrating <s>Unix</s> Linux drivers and so on. This will be another problem which will come after.

Comment: 1. Ubuntu is a Linux based OS, not Unix. 2. If Ubuntu was installed in a BIOS machine or in Legacy mode in a UEFI machine then you can't dual-boot just like that. This is likely the situation here if EasyUEFI in Windows doesn't detect the Ubuntu bootloader. 3. It's much easier and much less time consuming to reinstall Ubuntu - the installer will take care of the dual-boot - and while at that do yourself a favor and install the desktop variant instead.

Comment: I would also suggest using GParted from a (desktop) live session and clean up the added drive (Device menu > Create partition table > choose "gpt" for consistency because Windows strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode). Then all you may have to do is to open UEFI settings and assure "Ubuntu" is selected as the first boot priority. The installer typically changes this setting automatically but not always.

Comment: You can select "install alongside..." or "something else" and do a manual partitioning keeping in mind that you should also select the ESP (EFI System Partition) that's already in the first drive, the one that already have Windows. There's no point in having an additional ESP in the second drive (usually not a problem but not recommended).

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto. So the GParted solution is an alternative to "reinstall Ubuntu" solution, correct? I installed this server a long time ago: it currently just work perfectly, I'm afraid to install it again from scratch.

Comment: No, the use of GParted was an addition to better prepare for a reinstallation.

Comment: Thanks. And what do you think about this walkthrough ? https://dannyda.com/2021/05/08/how-to-convert-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-from-bios-to-uefi/

Comment: It's doable but you don't have to do part of it. Resizing the main partition and creating a new ESP is not needed and not recommended when you have one already. If you want to try it then first disable Windows' Fast Startup feature and shutdown Windows properly to make the setting stick. Then you can try that method minus the aforementioned part. The guide assumes Ubuntu as standalone (and no ESP).

Comment: It appears that my Lunix HDD is using MBR, so I need to convert to GPT first. This begins to be a bit too complicated to me, so I think I'm going with the "reinstall ubuntu" solution. I should have less driver problems this way.

Comment: Yes, do that. As commented before *It's much easier and much less time consuming to reinstall Ubuntu* and with expected better results in the end. That said, you actually don't need to convert (which can be done with little risk for Windows partitions with the mbr2gpt software but not really for Linux partitions) because the GPT requirement for UEFI mode is a Windows thing. Grub can boot Ubuntu in UEFI mode installed in MBR (but perhaps it shouldn't).

Comment: This is why in a previous comment (re: reinstallation) I suggested blanking the drive with a new partition table in GPT for "consistency" (and because GPT is far superior; don't use MBR unless you have to like for Windows 10 or older in old BIOS machines, Windows 11 can't be installed in BIOS mode/MBR), not because Ubuntu requires it.